# SQLiteDatabase select in array limit first value

Tags: sql, sqlite, select

My query :

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*, t3.* 
FROM table1 t1, table2 t2, table3 t3
WHERE t1.id = t2.idT1 AND t2.id = t3.idT2 AND 
t3.value IN (1,2,3,4)
```

But i want only the first row of table3 for value in array.
Example : if value = 2, i want only this record and not others where value = 3 or 4.

A subrequest is obligatory ?

Comment: Promote the use of  explict `JOIN` sintaxis, Aaron Bertrand wrote a nice article [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just sort by value and limit the result to one row.

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*, t3.* 
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2
  ON t1.id = t2.idT1
JOIN table3 t3
  ON t2.id = t3.idT2
WHERE t3.value IN (0,2,25,75)
ORDER BY t3.value
LIMIT 1
```

After your order comment: you need to add a custom order. This way even if `t3.value` match several values you still get the first one.

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN t3.value = 75 THEN 1
              WHEN t3.value = 2  THEN 2
              WHEN t3.value = 25 THEN 3
              WHEN t3.value = 0  THEN 4
         END
```

Comment: yes but limit 1 must be only for table3 and array can have value not in order (75,2,25,0)

Comment: That wasn't what you asked.  `(75,2,25,) == (0,2,25,75)` You need to explain what `First` mean

Comment: Thank you @Juan Carlos Oropeza, i must check differents results but it's look good.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a WHERE t3.value = 2  not an IN (1,2,3,4). Please use JOINS and not this type of linking to other tables.

The reason why you were getting 2,3,4 was because this was in your query **IN (1,2,3,4)**

```
SELECT t1., t2., t3.* 
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 on t1.id =   t2.idT1
JOIN table3 t3 on  t2.id = t3.idT2 
Where t3.value = 2
```

Comment: I dont think op know if value is `(1,2,3,4)` but he doesnt want all, just the first one

Comment: I thought so too until I looked at his sample. I thought he wanted to find a way to write where he can specify the value he wants. The grammar and sample is awkward. At least he has both sample.

Comment: @Manu then Juan Carlos Oropeza suggestion below should work for you.

Comment: Both your version of the command and the OPs use *exactly the same JOINs* with a slight difference in syntax.  There is *no reason* to prefer one over the other in this example.

Comment: @LarryLustig Yes I use `JOIN` version but the difference is on the `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`